# How to convert String representation of an array to an ArrayList?

Tags: java

```
//String representation of an array/list with two JSON string representations inside of it
String arrayOfTwoJSONString = "[{\"a\": \"sampleA\", \"b\": \"sampleB\"}, {\"c\": \"sampleC\", \"d\": \"sampleD\"}]";
```

How can I convert this to an Array or ArrayList that contains two String representations of the JSONs?

Comment: any reason you want to split this to an array of String and not convert it directly to an array of map ? in other word, parse the JSon

Comment: You can try with this approach 

String arrayOfTwoJSONString = "[{\"a\": \"sampleA\", \"b\": \"sampleB\"}, {\"c\": \"sampleC\", \"d\": \"sampleD\"}]";
  
List<String> of = List.of(arrayOfTwoJSONString.split(","));
of.stream().forEach(System.out::println);